# Upload small changes to a production server in angular

Tags: angular, deployment, angular5, angular6

Good evening everyone, I have a doubt that happens when I have a relatively heavy application and is in production,
What happens when I only have to fix a small change like for example: change the color of the navbar or change the style of
letter of a modal in a component, it is necessary to compile the whole project of angular? or can I somehow just compile
That small change?